# Django context processor being called twice per request

Tags: python, django

I've found only one topic like this and not a single answer in there seems to work.
I have two context processors:

```
def cart_view(request):
    try:
        cart_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
        request.session['total'] = cart.items.count()
        print('OLD CART USED')
    except:
        cart = Cart()
        cart.save()
        cart_id = cart.id
        request.session['cart_id'] = cart_id
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
        print('NEW CART CREATED')
    return {'cart':cart}

# dropdown menu categories to every page
def categories(request):
    print('CATEGORIES CONTEXT PROCCESOR')
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return {'dropdown_categories':categories}
```

Settings:

```
            'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.media',
            'shopping.views.cart_view',
            'shopping.views.categories',
             ]
```

Via those print statements I'm able to see that each one of those CP being executed twice per request, although I'm rendering just `base.html`. What may be the problem?

`import traceback; traceback.print_stack()` gives this two times:

P.S. I know that I'm querying the DB every time I use CP, I'll add caching later.

Cosole log(that's one page load):

```
OLD CART USED
CATEGORIES CONTEXT PROCCESOR
[30/Aug/2018 18:56:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2651
OLD CART USED
CATEGORIES CONTEXT PROCCESOR
[30/Aug/2018 18:56:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2651
```

View:

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'base.html'
```

Project URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [re_path(r'^',include('shopping.urls',namespace='shop'))]
```

App's URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [re_path(r'^$',views.HomePageView.as_view(),name='home')]
```

Comment: Did you perhaps added the context processor twice in the settings?

Comment: Added settings to the question.

Comment: do you have any inclusion_tag or anything else rendering a template (in addition to the one rendered by the view) ?

Comment: [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/issues/353) appears to call the context processors for a second time.

Comment: I don't seem to use it. I tried switching off 'django.template.context_processors.debug' — it doesn't work

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have one templete tag per each keyword. {{cart.items.count}} and {% for category in dropdown_categories %}

Comment: The django debug toolbar and `            'django.template.context_processors.debug'` are two different things. If you show the full console output that show the context processors being called twice per request, it might indicate what is going on.

Comment: @bloodwithmilk there's your own code and there's what your own code calls. Django debug toolbar DO render a template, so if you have it installed then look no further.

Comment: I don't use django debug toolbar.

Comment: Adding `import traceback; traceback.print_stack()` to the context processor might also help you debug the issue.

Comment: Added console log.

Comment: What is the actual view you are accessing? Putting the context processors in `views.py` is confusing, since they are not views.

Comment: Added view. I've just started using context processors, in the future I'll put in the separate file.

Comment: Does your request gets redirected because of missing trailing slash or http to https or abcd,com to www.abcd.com?

Comment: OK, the `print_stack()` output doesn't look very useful in this case. Please show the console output without it. Please copy and paste the text instead of posting screenshots.

Comment: Added console log

Comment: The request is logged TWO times

Comment: For some reason it happens two times per page load

Comment: The output shows `[30/Aug/2018 18:56:13] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2651` *twice*. That's two requests. The print lines show the context processor was only called once per request.

Comment: Any ideas why it sends two request per one page load? I've already disabled everything I could, still the same

Comment: Perhaps you have some JavaScript doing an AJAX request. Or perhaps Atom is doing something funny - you could check if you get the same output when you run `manage.py runserver` manually. Apart from that I don't have any suggestions.

Comment: I do actualy... But it's on the completly different page. Let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't what magic is this but the issue of getting two requests per page load had something to do with this line of code in my `base.html`:

```
<img src="#" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
```

As soon as I deleted it, everything started to work normaly...

Comment: The browser exapands the relative url `#` to `http://example.org/#`, so the browser makes a request to `/` to try load the image (the `#` and anything after it isn't sent to the server).

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help:)